# How to change the default language of Facebook share page on iPad?

Tags: ipad, sharing, facebook

Whenever I want to share something on Facebook using another app on iPad, the Facebook login page show in Chineese.
I can change this by choosing English at the bottom of this login page but after I login the following pages would be still in Chineese.

How can I change the default language?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set your default language on Facebook on English (in account parameters) ?
What is the language you use on the iPad and on Facebook right now ?

**EDIT :** after some tests it's seems that is more Facebook API related (because the problem is on several apps at a time).
Either developers don't call correctly the Facebook login, or it's a bug.

Comment: Both my iPad's and Facebook account's language are set to English.

Comment: From which app(s) did you try to share content ? The problem is on every app or just on or two for example ?

Comment: I tried on Ted, Pulse and Flipboard.

Comment: Just try with TediSub and I have the Facebook dialog in Bahasa Indonesia. But I don't have any problem on Flipboard. Seems to me that the problem is on the app. Are you up to date with Flipboard ?

Comment: Every app is up to date. Tedisub is not a free app and I don't think I'll give it a try.

Comment: Just tried with the TED app : same problem than TEDiSub. Maybe it concern the Facebook API used in apps to connect with Facebook profile. I don't have another idea for the moment sorry.